# Fancybox 4 transition effect

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How can i change facybox 4 transition effect from slide to fade? I have a simple photo gallery, created with

```
data-fancybox="galleryName"
```

I have tried initialize fancybox via

```
Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox="galleryName"]', {
  transitionEffect : "fade"
})
```

but looks like it only works with fancybox v3?

Comment: Please upgrade to Fancybox5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch from Fancybox 4 to latest fancybox 3 and insert following code

```
$.fancybox.defaults[ 'transitionEffect' ] = 'fade' === "" ? false : 'fade';
$.fancybox.defaults[ 'transitionDuration' ] = 'transitionEffect' === 'fade' ? 330 : 550;
```

Comment: Sorry, transition effects will be included in the next release.

Comment: Thank you, looking looking forward to it